# Search in menu & submenu with JQuery Searchable plugin - multilevel

Tags: javascript, jquery, searchable

I want to search in menu title and submenu, but in `JQuery Searchable Plugin` can't find this option. When I type characters, I can find menu but can't find submenu. `Searchable plugin` has `childSelector` option but this option is searching just the first level.

```js
$('#menu-list').searchable({
    searchField: '#menu-list-search',
    selector: 'li',
    childSelector: '.menu-text',
    show: function( elem ) {
        elem.slideDown(100);
    },
    hide: function( elem ) {
        elem.slideUp( 100 );
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stidges/jquery-searchable/master/dist/jquery.searchable-1.0.0.min.js"></script>

<input id="menu-list-search" placeholder="Search Menu...">

<ul id="menu-list" class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="">
    <a href="index.html">
      <i class="menu-icon fa fa-tachometer"></i>
      <span class="menu-text"> menu1 </span>
    </a>

    <b class="arrow"></b>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
      <i class="menu-icon fa fa-list"></i>
      <span class="menu-text"> menu2 </span>

      <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
    </a>

    <b class="arrow"></b>

    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="">
        <a href="tables.html">
          <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
         submenu1
        </a>

        <b class="arrow"></b>
      </li>

      <li class="">
        <a href="jqgrid.html">
          <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
          submenu2
        </a>

        <b class="arrow"></b>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes In HTML**

Wrap all text (including submenu items) with

```
<span>text_here</span>
```

**Changes in JS**

and simply change the value of childSelector to 'span'

```
...
...
childSelector: 'span',
...
...
```

Comment: thanks a lot , but I located all text in <span class="menu-text">

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved with wrap all text in  `<span class="menu-text"> menu1 </span>`